# Self-reference in F# sequence expression

Tags: f#, sequence

Is there a way to have a self-reference in F# sequence expression? For example:

```
[for i in 1..n do if _f(i)_not_in_this_list_ do yield f(i)]
```

which prevents inserting duplicate elements.

EDIT: In general case, I would like to know the contents of this_list before applying f(), which is very computationally expensive.

EDIT: I oversimplified in the example above. My specific case is a computationally expensive test T (T: int -> bool) having a property T(i) => T(n*i) so the code snippet is:

```
[for i in 1..n do if _i_not_in_this_list_ && T(i) then for j in i..i..n do yield j]
```

The goal is to reduce the number of T() applications and use concise notation. I accomplished the former by using a mutable helper array:

```
let mutable notYet = Array.create n true
[for i in 1..n do if notYet.[i] && T(i) then for j in i..i..n do yield j; notYet.[j] <- false]
```

Comment: One alternative would be to convert to a set and then back to a seq

Comment: @John: Duplicate elements is just a simple example. In general case, I would like to know the contents of _this_list_ before calling f(), which is very computationally expensive. I will edit the question to this effect.

Comment: You're simply using the wrong data structure here.

Comment: @ildjarn: What is your suggestion? Something along the lines of wmeyer's answer below?

Comment: @Paul : Indeed – assuming `f` is idempotent, memoization of a single value is **exactly** what a (hash)set is for.

Answer (score 2):

You can have recursive [sequence expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233209.aspx) e.g.

```
let rec allFiles dir =
    seq { yield! Directory.GetFiles dir
          for d in Directory.GetDirectories dir do
              yield! allFiles d }
```

but circular reference is not possible.

An alternative is to use [Seq.distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353698.aspx) from [Seq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353635.aspx) module:

```
seq { for i in 1..n -> f i }
|> Seq.distinct
```

or to convert sequence to set using [Set.ofSeq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340225.aspx) before consumption as per @John's comment.

Answer (score 2):

You may also decide to maintain information about the previously generated elements in an explicit way; for example:

```
let genSeq n =
   let elems = System.Collections.Generic.HashSet()
   seq {
      for i in 1..n do
         if not (elems.Contains(i)) then
            elems.Add(i) |> ignore
            yield i
   }
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing: mutable helper object to keep track of elements in the list being constructed. I was looking for a better way.

Comment: How about `if elems.Add(i) then yield i`? That way you get the same output for half as many Hashset lookups.

Answer (score 2):

There are several considerations here.
**First,** you can't check if `f(i)` is in a list or not before actually computing `f(i)`. So I guess you meant that your `check` function is expensive, not `f(i)` itself. Correct me if I'm wrong.

**Second,** if `check` is *indeed* very computationally expensive, you may look for a more effective algorithm. There's no guarantee you will find one for every sequence, but they often exist. Then your code will be nothing but a single `Seq.unfold`.

**Third.** When there's no such optimization, you may take another approach. Within `[for...yield]`, you only build a current element and you can't access prior ones. Instead of returning an element, building an entire list manually seems to be the way to go:

```
// a simple algorithm checking if some F(x) exists in a sequence somehow
let check (x:string) xs = Seq.forall (fun el -> not (x.Contains el)) xs
// a converter i -> something else
let f (i: int) = i.ToString()

let generate f xs =
    let rec loop ys = function
        | [] -> List.rev ys
        | x::t ->
            let y = f x
            loop (if check y ys then y::ys else ys) t
    loop [] xs

// usage
[0..3..1000] |> generate f |> List.iter (printf "%O ")
```

Comment: I edited the question again - sorry for ambiguity. You are right in 1. Lets assume that the check function is proven to be O(n!) or something similarly bad, so no hope for 2. Good suggestion with generate function.